# Double negative Q/A?

Tags: negation

If someone asks "Can I not have a drink?", and someone else responds "No", is that considered as:

- No = No, you **can't not** have a drink. = You can have a drink.

or

- No = No, you **can't** have a drink. = You can't have a drink

Comment: In the abstract, it is ambiguous. In context, with tone of voice and body language, it will usually be clear which is meant.

Comment: "Mind if I sit here?" "Yeah, okay." - Language is intuitive. Rules can only take you so far.

Comment: This question seems relevant: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239647/why-is-no-used-instead-of-yes-in-this-conversation/239662#239662

Comment: Yes, we have no bananas.

Answer (score 1):

In English, as opposed to some other languages, the answer "yes" or "no" to a yes or no question is not affected by whether the question is in the affirmative or negative. 
Another example: Do you have a car? Yes (I have a car), 
vs Don't you have a car? Yes (I have a car). The answer is the same despite how the question is framed.

Answer (score 1):

The wording of the initial question "Can I not have a drink?" is slightly awkward unless used in the context "Everybody else is having a drink, but I would rather not have one; may I please be exempt from having a drink?"

In that case, I would interpret "no" to mean "no, you are obligated to have a drink."

Comment: You mean the OP's question cannot be interpreted as "_Can't I have a drink_?"? In that case a negative answer would mean "_No, you can't have any._".